# Django static files 404 (Not Found)

Tags: python, css, django, reactjs

I am trying to include static files not located within the band app, but in a separate directory called **static**.

This directory contains a **build** directory, which contains CSS & JS directories.

Along with the files inside the CSS and JS directories, I'd also like to include minified files such as jquery, react and browser which are inside the **bower_components** directory.

My project structure below:

```
Music/
├── band/
│   ├── migrations/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── music/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── node_modules/
├── static/
├──── static/
│     ├── bower_components/
│     ├── build/
│     ├── css/
│     ├── images/
│     └── js/
├── templates/
      ├── band/
      ├── MasterPages/
      ├── index.html
```

My settings.py within **music** contains the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Broski/PycharmProjects/Music/static'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Broski/PycharmProjects/Music/upload'
```

This MasterPage.html file is located in the **MasterPages** directory, under templates:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Music</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'build/css/main.css' %}" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/react/react.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/babel/browser.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="{% static 'build/js/indexReact.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load the website, the template renders but the static files do not. I get a 404 error.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css 
127.0.0.1/:22 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 
127.0.0.1/:23 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/react/react.min.js 
127.0.0.1/:26 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/babel/browser.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see, I need React, Jquery and Browser to load correctly to continue this youtube tutorial:

[Building a website with Django and React.js Video 1: Defining our project structure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxjJ7siCK44&index=1&list=PLei96ZX_m9sUs4aFBvxQDKAE1tg2kN01e)

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fixed.

I confused **STATIC_ROOT** and **STATICFILES_DIRS**

Therefore I removed static_root and replaced to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

Where base dir just points to my project folder.